# To remove double quotes from vector<string> c++ 98

Tags: c++, string, vector, c++98, erase-remove-idiom

I am trying to remove the double quotes characters from my vector string value.

for eg: if my vector string has values (50,40,"50GB","40GB",60). i am trying refine the vector by erasing Double quotes(" "). so the my final vector (50,40,50GB,40GB,60).

Below is the piece of code I tried to make it work, I got compilation issue saying... Please help me with fixing this issue and to achieve the desired result.

```
In function ‘void removeCharsFromVectorString(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
strErase.cpp:28:27: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
           if(str[p][i] == " \" ")

Code: 
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void removeCharsFromVectorString( vector<string> &str)
    {
       for(int p = 0; p < str.size(); p++)
       {
          for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < str[p].length() ; ++i )
          {
              if(str[p][i] == " \" ")
              {
                  str[p].erase(i, 1);
                  i--;
              }
              //str.erase( remove(str.begin(), str.end(), charsToRemove[i]), str.end() );
          }
       }
      for(int p = 0; p < str.size(); p++)
       {
          cout<<str[p]<<endl;
       }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
       vector<string> str; 
       str.push_back("50");
       str.push_back("40");
       str.push_back("\"50GB\"");
       str.push_back("\"40GB\"");
       str.push_back("60");
       removeCharsFromVectorString(str);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is not possible since "50GB" is a string and therefore needs the double quotes. If you remove the "GB" you can then parse 50 as integer.

Comment: @PhilipF. for the better understanding, i have made changes for vector push_back in main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str[p][i] is of type char, so you need to compare it to a char. Putting your double quote in two single quotes should do the trick:

```
if(str[p][i] == '"')
{
    str[p].erase(i, 1);
    i--;
 }
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void removeCharsFromVectorString( vector<string> &str)
{
    for(int p = 0; p < str.size(); p++)
    {
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < str[p].length() ; ++i )
        {
            if(str[p][i] == '"')
            {
                str[p].erase(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
            //str.erase( remove(str.begin(), str.end(), charsToRemove[i]), str.end() );
        }
    }
    for(int p = 0; p < str.size(); p++)
    {
        cout<<str[p]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> str; 
    str.push_back("50");
    str.push_back("40");
    str.push_back("\"50GB\"");
    str.push_back("\"40GB\"");
    str.push_back("60");
    removeCharsFromVectorString(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

50
40
50GB
40GB
60

Answer (score 0):

`str[p]` gives you a `string&` so a reference to a string. Then you do another `[]`, so `str[p][i]` which gives you a `char&`. Then you try to compare this to `" \" "` which is a c style string (ie. a `char const *`) which. This doesn't work.

I think you are trying to compare it to `'"'` so the char representing double quotes. This way you compare apples with apples.

Besides:

Consider what happens if you encouter `""` in your string. Erase the first, then coninue iterating after the seconds, since your string is now shorter.